# Pytorch AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to run code from [this repo](https://github.com/eladhoffer/captionGen). I have disabled cuda by changing lines 39/40 in main.py from

```
parser.add_argument('--type', default='torch.cuda.FloatTensor', help='type of tensor - e.g torch.cuda.HalfTensor')
```

to

```
parser.add_argument('--type', default='torch.FloatTensor', help='type of tensor - e.g torch.HalfTensor')
```

Despite this, running the code gives me the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 190, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 178, in main
    model, train_data, training=True, optimizer=optimizer)
  File "main.py", line 135, in forward
    for i, (imgs, (captions, lengths)) in enumerate(data):
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 201, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 221, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
AssertionError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 62, in _pin_memory_loop
    batch = pin_memory_batch(batch)
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 123, in pin_memory_batch
    return [pin_memory_batch(sample) for sample in batch]
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 123, in <listcomp>
    return [pin_memory_batch(sample) for sample in batch]
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 117, in pin_memory_batch
    return batch.pin_memory()
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 82, in pin_memory
    return type(self)().set_(storage.pin_memory()).view_as(self)
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/storage.py", line 83, in pin_memory
    allocator = torch.cuda._host_allocator()
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 220, in _host_allocator
    _lazy_init()
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 84, in _lazy_init
    _check_driver()
  File "/Users/lakshay/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 51, in _check_driver
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

Spent some time looking through the issues in the Pytorch github, to no avail. Help, please?

Comment: did you assure that `use_cuda` is indeed `False` in `def forward`?

Comment: Yep, I manually changed that to `use_cuda = False` (even though it logically would yield `False` anyway after the change I made above)

Comment: add `pin_memory=False` to the `get_iterator(...)` function like `get_iterator(..., pin_memory=False)`. The function is called twice here: https://github.com/eladhoffer/captionGen/blob/master/main.py#L96-L105

Comment: @blckbird that worked; thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look into the [data.py](https://github.com/eladhoffer/captionGen/blob/master/data.py) file, you can see the function:

```
def get_iterator(data, batch_size=32, max_length=30, shuffle=True, num_workers=4, pin_memory=True):
    cap, vocab = data
    return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        cap,
        batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle,
        collate_fn=create_batches(vocab, max_length),
        num_workers=num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory)
```

which is called twice in [main.py](https://github.com/eladhoffer/captionGen/blob/master/main.py#L96-L105) file to get an iterator for the train and dev data. If you see the [DataLoader](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) class in pytorch, there is a parameter called:

> pin_memory (bool, optional) – If True, the data loader will copy tensors into CUDA pinned memory before returning them.

which is by default `True` in the `get_iterator` function. And as a result you are getting this error. You can simply pass the `pin_memory` param value as `False` when you are calling `get_iterator` function as follows.

```
train_data = get_iterator(get_coco_data(vocab, train=True),
                          batch_size=args.batch_size,
                          ...,
                          ...,
                          ...,
                          pin_memory=False)
```

Answer (score 11):

Removing `.cuda()` works for me on macOS.

Comment: in linux too, it did.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had not installed PyTorch with Cuda enabled in my Anaconda environment. Note that you need a CUDA enabled GPU for this to work.

Follow this link to install PyTorch for the specific version of Cuda you have: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

In my case I installed this version:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch

Comment: This one's as good as the first one. Helped!

Answer (score 2):

So I'm using a Mac, trying to create a Neural Net with cuda like

```
net = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(28*28, 100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(100, 100),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(100, 10),
    nn.LogSoftmax()
).cuda()
```

My mistake was that I was trying to create nn, while Macs don't have CUDA.
So if anyone facing the same problem just remove the `.cuda()` and you code should work.

Edit:

You can't do GPU computations without CUDA. And unfortunately for people who have Intel integrated graphics, CUDA can't be installed because it's only compatible for NVIDIA GPUs.

If you have a NVIDIA graphic card, it's probably that CUDA is already installed on our system, if not you can install it.

You can buy external graphics compatible with your computer but that alone will take around $300, not to mention the problem of connectivity.

Otherwise you can use :
Google-Colaboratory, Kaggle Kernels (Free)
AWS, GCP(free credits), PaperSpace (Paid)

Comment: And how do you suggest to do those computations on GPU afterwards? I mean I don't use mac but my PC has intel-integrated and all I use is Google-colab to do my projects. So like is it necessary for me to install CUDA on my device as well?

Answer (score 2):

When experiencing this problem with Detectron2, adding the below code fixes the problem.

```
cfg.MODEL.DEVICE = "cpu"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Activate the Correct Environment where the torch is installed.
  ex: conda activate "environment name"

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76225251/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).